# The constant of the Normal law

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

This is a sequel of the question [Using Mathematica to derive the PDF of the normal distribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45564/using-mathematica-to-derive-the-pdf-of-the-normal-distribution).

```
sol = DSolve[ϕ'[x] == -k (x - μ)/σ^2 ϕ[x], ϕ[x], x]
```

Gives the Normal law distribution up to a parameter. ---C[1]---. Unfortunately this C[1] is the solution of

```
Solve [(Integrate[sol[[1, 1, 2]] /. C[1] -> a , {x, -∞, ∞}]) == 1, a]
```

but after one hour Mathematica fails to find a solution. It fails also to find the solution with boundary conditions

Comment: The problem is that `Integrate` returns a `ConditionalExpression`; try evaluating the integral first to see what I mean. To get around this, do `Integrate[sol[[1, 1, 2]] /. C[1] -> a , {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions->{k > 0, μ > 0, σ > 0}]` and try again.

Comment: @march $\mu$ doesn't have to be positive.

Comment: @corey979. Right, the condition on $\mu$ is unnecessary. I was just trying to get the point across.

Comment: Of course, if I have seen somebody asking such a question without Assumptions, I would have tell him. Buut I am so absentminded. Sorry. This is a point but not the all story. I have simplified in setting $k=0$ . But the integral is an infinite object and you cannot apply Solve to this tyope of object

Comment: of course it was a typesetting mistake $k=0$ was $k=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to set `k = 0`

```
sol = ϕ[x] /. 
  DSolve[ϕ'[x] == -k (x - μ)/σ^2 ϕ[x], ϕ[x], x][[1]]

(*  E^((k*(-(x^2/2) + x*μ))/σ^2)*C[1]  *)

Assuming[{k > 0, σ > 0},
 sol /. Solve[
     Integrate[sol, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 1, C[1]][[1]] // 
  Simplify]

(*  Sqrt[k]/(E^((k*(x - μ)^2)/
           (2*σ^2))*(Sqrt[2*Pi]*σ))  *)
```

A simple form would be `k = 1`